# Any good IIS Tracer?

Tags: iis-6, trace

I'm trying to find an IIS Tracer to be able to look at all requests on my ASP.NET application.
I found the [IISTracer](http://iismonitor.motobit.com/) tool which looks great. The problem is that my server is running with an AMD64 architecture which is not compatible with this software (the ISAPI filter fails when restarting IIS).

Do you guys know any other option? I'm running Windows 2k3 with IIS6.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you need currently running requests, or just recent requests?  You may want to consider LogParser and running directly against your IIS Logs.  You can get impressive results in near real time.  It supports checkpoints too so it will only give results since the last time you ran it.  Various stats programs like SmarterStats are good for that too.

Comment: I'd like to have the running requests too, but I'd be ok without too. I've looked on these IIS6 logs and it appears that it doesn't output the response time, is it true?

Comment: Actually, I just found out that i can customize which information will be logged. I'll be trying this.

Comment: Yes, time-taken is the one you probably one.  Turn on referrer and the bytes fields too.  As for running requests IIS7 addresses it nicely, but for IIS6 you'll need a 3rd party tool.  I don't know of any free or inexpensive ones.  So, the running requests is difficult, but the on-going requests is definitely possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) and Follow TCP stream?

Comment: That's a good option. But I'm looking for something that is on a higher level and that does not go too deep. The output from IISTracer is exactly what I'm looking for. The HTTP Method, Client IP, Length, URL, Response Time.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using a tool like Paros Proxy:

http://www.parosproxy.org/functions.shtml

It runs client side so it won't give you view of "all requests", but it could help you debug a session that you control.

Comment: I'm already using firebug to trace my own requests. But I'd like to log requests from everyone.